# An HTML 5 only Business-Oriented application

Tags: html

I am planning to create a HTML5 web application. I have a couple of queries though-:

I wished to know if it is possible to create a business oriented application using HTML5 only without a backbone like Asp.Net. I found a lot of articles on google suggesting the use of Asp.Net MVC, or ASP.Net website as a base template but none suggesting a HTML+js alone approach.

Given the web standards update for VS 2010 SP1 and js libraries like Modernizr, is it possible to create an app completely in HTML5 using Visual Studio.

Comment: Sure, but it really depends on your application. What's a "business oriented application"?

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You're eventually going to want to do some server side work, and for that you would need either Java, PHP, or ASP set up to intercept and process commands... you could go ahead and create everything in HTML+JS alone, and use the file writer for "*permanent storage*" but that's really cutting corners, and can lead to catastrophe down the line depending on where exactly you are trying to take this application of yours.